# How to filter Ajax requests in javascript

Tags: ajax, jquery

Is is possible to filter out some Ajax Requests based on some URLs ?
I don't want to write code in every AJAX request like if url matches with "A" then make the call otherwise not. There is something like ajaxStart method but I do not receive ajax request url in that function. So The way I am trying to solve this is:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (settings.url == "A") return false; // Filter out URLs Try-1
        if (settings.url == "A") settings.url = "#"; // Loop on same page Try-2
    }
 });
```

Q1. I think if we return false from beforeSend then ajax call is not made. Am i right ? - **YES**

Q2. Updating settings.url does actually change the url of ajax object and now the ajax call is prevented to same page. Is this right ?

Please tell me if there is something wrong I am doing ?

Comment: Q1: Yes, you're correct. From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/): "Returning `false` in the `beforeSend` function will cancel the request."

Comment: Please explain more why you want to "filter" your outbound AJAX requests?... Otherwise if you don't want to make the request just don't make it... No issue.

Comment: Thanks Anthony for confirmation :)